# Easiest way to convert a number into years and months

Tags: javascript

I have a script that generates a number and sets it to a textbox.  If, for example, the number was 6.3, I'd want to be able to convert this into 6 years 4 months.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: What is you expected output ? a string ? 2 numbers ? and how does 6.3 = 6 years and **4** months ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = 6.3;
var y = Math.floor(n);            // whole years
var m = Math.floor(12 * (n - y)); // treat remainder as fraction of a year
```

I note that this gives 3 for the month, not 4.  Why do you think 6.3 should give 4 months?  6 years and 4 months is 6.333333 years.

Answer (score 1):

Im really not sure if you want to create a date/number from your input or just split the numbers and make a string ? i went for the second one !

```
var number = 6.3;
var splitstring = number.toString().split('.');
var years = splitstring[0];
var months = splitstring[1];
alert(years + ' years,' + months + ' months');​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaAWK/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDescription(str)
{
    var description = "";
    var years = 0;
    var months = 0;
    var splits = str.split('.');
    if(splits.length >= 1)
    {
       years = parseInt(splits[0]);
    }
    if(splits.length >= 2)
    {
       months = parseInt(splits[1]);
    }
    return years + ' years' + ' ' + months + ' months';
}
```

call with

```
getDescription('6.3');
```

or

```
getDescription(document.getElementById('my_textbox').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 8.62;
console.log("%d year/s and %d month/s", ~~num, ~~((num - ~~num)*12)); 
/* 8 year/s and 7 month/s */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 6.3
var years = Math.floor(n);
var months = Math.round((n * 12) % 12);
```

% means modulus and it returns the remainder of the division, while round, rounds a number to its nearest integer.

So...

- Math.floor(6.3) will return 6 years
- (6.3 * 12) % 12 will return 3.6 months
- round(3.6) will return 4 months **and this explains why 6.3
  years is like 6 years and 4 months**.